# process algebra: a verification tools

Tags: software, process-algebra

I would like to find a free software (running under Windows 8) which could simulate every single step of Process Algebras of the most general form as given in the Handbook of Process Algebras and some of decidable questions about decidable problems about them. I.e. esp. I do not want that it would be limited to linear time, colored,finite-state or otherwise restricted class of them from the very beginning. I understand that many questions will be undecidable, but I still want to design my own model in this generality and simulate it step by step.

Comment: This is probably not the answer you were hoping for, but process algebras in general are Turing complete, so you need a general purpose programming language to simulate process algebras in general. Any normal programming language will do.

Comment: @MartinBerger I'm aware of what you write, **but** in the first place I need a **graphical enviroment** for those process algebras.

Comment: I don't understand why you need a graphical environment for understanding process algebra. I wrote a PhD about them without a graphical environment. PAs are a theoretical tool. A mathematical abstraction. You can implement your own simulator.